Apex InvoiceUpload Class Error - Invalid File Format Error from AWS
I'm hoping to get some help with an error I'm encountering in my Salesforce Apex class. The class is designed to upload invoices to Salesforce and then send them to an AWS API. I'm getting an error message back from AWS that says:

Invalid file format, must be one of the following types: PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG, JFIF, BMP, TIFF

Here's the relevant code from my Apex class:
public class InvoiceUpload {
  // ... (class code omitted for brevity)

  public static void uploadFileToAWS(Id contentVersionId) {
    try {
      // ... (code to query ContentVersion omitted for brevity)

      // Prepare the body for the HTTP request
      String boundary = 'Boundary-' + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
      String invoiceBase64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cv.VersionData);
      String body = '--' + boundary + '\r\n' +
                     'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="' + cv.Title + '"\r\n' +
                     'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n' +
                     invoiceBase64 + '\r\n' +
                     '--' + boundary + '--';
      
      // ... (remaining code omitted for brevity)
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // ... (exception handling omitted for brevity)
    }
  }
}

The error message seems to indicate that the file being uploaded is not in a supported format. I've checked and confirmed that the cv.VersionData field contains the contents of the uploaded file.
For tests, I'm uploading a PDF file.
Has anyone else encountered this error before? Any insights into what might be causing the issue or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.
Please note: I've hidden the endpoint and authorization token in the code snippet for security purposes.
What I tried:

I wrote an Apex class to upload invoices to Salesforce and then send them to an AWS API.
The class queries the ContentVersion record to retrieve the uploaded file data.
It then prepares an HTTP request with the file data encoded in base64 and sends it to the AWS endpoint.

What I expected:

The AWS API to successfully receive the uploaded invoice file.
The API would validate the file format and process it accordingly.
My Apex class would receive a successful response (status code 200) from AWS.

What actually happened:

The AWS API returned an error indicating an Invalid file format
This suggests that the uploaded file was not in one of the supported formats accepted by the AWS API (PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG, JFIF, BMP, TIFF).


What do you mean by "sends it to the AWS endpoint"? What Endpoint is that?

It's a Holmes API that receives an invoice, reads the data from the file {OCR}, and returns a JSON utilizing the OpenAI API.

Which line of code is generating the error?

In this part of the code:
       `HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://blablabla/api/v1/invoice');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer blablabla');
        request.setBody(body);`


You did not show that code in your Question. It appears that you are uploading to an API Gateway endpoints backed by an AWS Lambda function? The fact that you got an error message back from it suggests that this connection is working fine. Is that API endpoint provided by this Holmes system, or is it a Lambda function in your own AWS account that you can access and examine?
